# Having to rebuild Report project to preview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

In VS2010, I'm having to rebuild a Report project every time to preview changes.

Before, I could just save to preview. Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Is this just in one report or all reports in a project?  Just one solution or all solutions?  I would try to uninstall just BIDS and reinstall if it affects all solutions.  If it is a specific report it seems that a memory is being kept that is not updated till a rebuild occurs.

Comment: All reports in project. Don't have another solution handy. Reinstall BIDS.... yeah.... just the thing to boost my productivity.

Comment: BIDS behavior is saving and being able to preview. What is your BIDS version? 2008, 2012?

Comment: Do they still call it BIDS? IDK... it's visual studio 2010. I have sql sever data tools installed also.

Comment: Business Intelligence Development Studio(BIDS), it is the add on from SQL Server 2012 then if you are using VS 2010 with it.  I am NOT CERTAIN with 2010 BIDS but I know I just reinstalled ONLY BIDS with SQL Server 2008 the other day and it took only about 20 minutes top.  I realize when people are developing in a production environment this is not what they want to hear.  Also you could attempt to try to boot VS 2010 into safe mode before beginning the process and see if that helps anything.